# Shuffling Algorithm for arrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, shuffle

I want to shuffle an array of containing a list of cities to generate a result. The requirement for this shuffling is that same city can only appear again after at least six different cities have appeared. The same city must appear only twice.

I messed up using a different scenario before but I am new on here and getting used to how to post codes that I am struggling with. Any help would be appreciated. `Array5` is the array to be shuffled.

Cities to be shuffled:

```
Boston, Durban, Melbourne, Paris, Denver, Algiers, Freetown, Sydney, Colorado, Oslo, Melbourne, Brussels
```

I have included my code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,j,count;

   char array1[3][10]={"Denver","Boston","Colorado"};
   char array2[3][10]={"Melbourne","Sydney","Canberra"};
   char array3[3][10]={"Paris","Brussels","Oslo"};
   char array4[3][10]={"Durban","Algiers","Freetown"};

   char array5[12][10];

   for (i=0;i<3;i++){
       strcpy(array5[i],array1[i]);
   }

   for (i=0;i<3;i++){
       strcpy(array5[i+3],array2[i]);
   }

   for (i=0;i<3;i++){
       strcpy(array5[i+6],array3[i]);
   }

   for (i=0;i<3;i++){
       strcpy(array5[i+9],array4[i]);
   }

   for (i=0;i<12;i++)
       printf("%s\t\n",array5[i]);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't sound random to me.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. While you're thinking about what to ask, please clarify what you're doing here. A pack of cards normally consists of 52 cards that are all different. The same card can never appear more than once after shuffling. If you're not talking about playing cards, please elaborate. How many cards are there. What is the purpose of these arbitrary rules about where and when they can appear. But at least ask a question somewhere.

Comment: The only ways to get a card three times from a pack are for (1) that pack to contain AT LEAST three of that card or (2)  cards are returned to the pack after selection.    Also, if you want a card to NOT reappear for a time and then reappear, then the selection is definitely not random.

Comment: If I have a similar problem to what I have posted before and I have tried using the shuffling algorithm here. Should I post the new question here or open a new post? I am new here hence the stupid question. Apologies in advance.

Comment: @Othello post your new problem as the new separate question. Definitely not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved in two steps.

1) We shuffle the auxiliary array to obtain initial placement of the cities.

We can use FisherYates shuffle algorithm for shuffling the initial array.

2) We randomly decide which city we want to duplicate. We have to be mindful of the restrictions. City can be doubled only one time. If the city is doubled then there are at least `6` cities between them.

More explanations in the code:

```
// The requirement for this shuffling is that same city can only appear again after at least six different cities have appeared.
// A city can only appear twice.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define STR_LEN                 16
#define NR_OF_ROWS               3
#define NR_OF_SMALL_ARRAYS       4
#define NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY  NR_OF_ROWS*NR_OF_SMALL_ARRAYS

#define DOUBLE_COUNTER          12 // number of tries to double the city

void copy(char dest[][STR_LEN], char source[][STR_LEN], size_t displacement)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<NR_OF_ROWS; i++){
      strcpy(dest[i+displacement], source[i]);
    }
}   

void init_shuffle(size_t array[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
        array[i] = i;
    }
}

void print_array(char array[][STR_LEN], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
         printf("%s ",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_shuffle(size_t array[], size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){
         printf("%zu ",array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_corresponding_cities(char array[][STR_LEN], size_t *shuffle, size_t size)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t j;

    for (i=0; i < size; i++){

        j = shuffle[i];

        printf("%s ", array[j] );
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int check_for_repeats(size_t *arr, size_t size, size_t value)
{
    size_t i;
    size_t counter = 0;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++){

       if(arr[i] == value){

           counter++;
           if(counter > 1)
              return 1;  // repeats found
       }  
    }
    return 0;  // no repeats       
}

int check_for_number_of_repeats(char array[][STR_LEN], size_t *arr, size_t size)
{
    size_t i, j;
    size_t counter = 0;
    size_t value;
    int repeats = 0;

    for (j=0; j<size; j++){    

        value = j;
        counter = 0;

        for (i=0; i<size; i++){

            if(arr[i] == value){

                counter++;

               if(counter > 1){
                  repeats++;               // repeats found
                  printf("%s ", array[j]); // print the city
                  break;
               }
            }
        }  
    }
    return repeats;          
}    

void FisherYatesShuffle(size_t *arr, int n) { 

     size_t i, j; // indexes
     size_t tmp;  // create local variables to hold values for shuffle

     for (i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {  // shuffle
         j = rand() % (i + 1);      // randomise j for shuffle
         tmp = arr[j];
         arr[j] = arr[i];
         arr[i] = tmp;
     }
}

int main()
{
    size_t i;
    int no_yes;
    size_t double_index;
    time_t t;

    size_t shuffle[NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY]; // keep the results

    char array1[NR_OF_ROWS][STR_LEN]={"Denver0","Boston1","Colorado2"};
    char array2[NR_OF_ROWS][STR_LEN]={"Melbourne3","Sydney4","Canberra5"};
    char array3[NR_OF_ROWS][STR_LEN]={"Paris6","Brussels7","Oslo8"};
    char array4[NR_OF_ROWS][STR_LEN]={"Durban9","Algiers10","FreeTown11"};
    char array5[NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY][STR_LEN];

    init_shuffle(shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);
    // Initial arrangement:
    copy(array5, array1, 0*NR_OF_ROWS);
    copy(array5, array2, 1*NR_OF_ROWS);
    copy(array5, array3, 2*NR_OF_ROWS);
    copy(array5, array4, 3*NR_OF_ROWS);

    printf("Initial arrangement:\n");
     print_shuffle(shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);
    print_array(array5, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);

    printf("\n");

    // Algorithm: 
    // Note:
    // The shuffling will be done on the auxilliary shuffle array
    // Once the shuffling is done we can print the cities base on shuffle array values

    // Steps.
    // 1. We shuffle existing cities.

    // 2. We randomly decide if we want to repeat the city.
    // 3. If yes, we choose a random city 
    //
    // 4. Now we have to repeat that city. The requirement is that if we repeat the city
    // then we have have at least 6 cities between them.
    // E.g. We want to repat city from index 0 then duplicated city can only be placed at index 7 to 11

    // Index Next city placement:
    //
    // 0     7-11  range 5     [7,8,9,10,11]
    // 1     8-11  range 4 
    // 2     9-11  range 3
    // 3     10-11 range 2   
    // 4     11 fixed position 
    // 5     no placement
    // x     if (x > 4) no placement possible
    //       else placement possible in the range  [x+7, 11] 
    //       size of the range is 5-x
    // 5. we can repeat that procees a few times (DOUBLE_COUNTER). Restriction: A given city can be repeated only 1 time.

    /* Intializes random number generator */
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    // 1. Shuffle
    printf("After the shuffle:\n");
    FisherYatesShuffle(shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);
    print_shuffle(shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);
    print_corresponding_cities(array5, shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);
    printf("\n");

    // 2. Add cities
    for(int i=0; i < DOUBLE_COUNTER; i++)
    {
        no_yes = rand() % 2; //  add? YES OR NO 

        if(no_yes == 0)      // NO
            continue;

        double_index = rand() %  NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY; // which city 

        if(double_index > 4)
             continue;      // NO placement possible

        // check for repeats
        int rep = check_for_repeats(shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY, shuffle[double_index]); 

        if(rep)
           continue; // city under this index has a double already 

        //-------------------------------------------------------   
        // OK we need to repeat the city
        if(double_index == 4)
        {
            shuffle[11] = shuffle[double_index];
            continue;
        }

        // now we have a choice:
        int choice = rand() % (5 - double_index);

        // random placement within the range:

        shuffle[double_index +7 + choice] = shuffle[double_index];
        //-------------------------------------------------------
    }

    // Results:

    printf("Final arrangement after adding double city/cities:\n");
    print_shuffle(shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);
    print_corresponding_cities(array5, shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);

    // Stats:
    printf("\nThese cites occure two times:\n");    
    int nr_rep = check_for_number_of_repeats(array5, shuffle, NR_OF_ROWS_IN_BIG_ARRAY);
    printf("\nNumber of repeated cities = %d\n", nr_rep);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Initial arrangement:                                                                                                                             
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11                                                                                                                        
Denver0 Boston1 Colorado2 Melbourne3 Sydney4 Canberra5 Paris6 Brussels7 Oslo8 Durban9 Algiers10 FreeTown11                                       

After the shuffle:                                                                                                                               
5 9 3 11 6 8 4 0 7 2 1 10                                                                                                                        
Canberra5 Durban9 Melbourne3 FreeTown11 Paris6 Oslo8 Sydney4 Denver0 Brussels7 Colorado2 Boston1 Algiers10                                       

Final arrangement after adding double city/cities:                                                                                               
5 9 3 11 6 8 4 0 5 2 1 6                                                                                                                         
Canberra5 Durban9 Melbourne3 FreeTown11 Paris6 Oslo8 Sydney4 Denver0 Canberra5 Colorado2 Boston1 Paris6                                          

These cites occure two times:                                                                                                                    
Canberra5 Paris6                                                                                                                                 
Number of repeated cities = 2
```